# Docker nodejs mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker, dockerfile

i will docker my app js. I run the order docker-compose up.
But i have error : app      | /bin/sh: 1: [: “npm”,: unexpected operator.

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:latest 
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package.json /usr/src/app/
RUN npm install
COPY . /usr/src/app
EXPOSE 3000
RUN ["npm", "start" ]
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "2"
services:
app:
  container_name: app
  restart: always
  build: .
  ports:
    - "3000:3000"
  links:
    - mongo
mongo:
  container_name: mongo
  image: mongo
  volumes:
    - ./data:/data/db
  ports:
    - "27017:27017"
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Double-check your Dockerfile.

`"npm"` is different from `“npm”`, notice the double quote `"` and `“`. You should
always use `"` (input from your keyboard) rather than `“`

then run the following command:

```
docker-compose up --build
```

Comment: i edit my Docker file with  `CMD [ “npm“, “start“ ]` and l have same error

Comment: You should remove all unnecessary whitespace in `Dockerfile`, try with this `Dockerfile` (Ctrl + A your file and replace with this) https://pastebin.com/raw/Dzu6KPYD
Then run `docker-compose up --build`

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `CMD` instruction instead of `RUN`.

Change this line:

```
RUN ["npm", "start"]
```

...to this:

```
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

The `CMD` instruction is triggered when your container starts.

Docs here:
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd

I hope this helps.